# change iOS tab bar item name when webpage button is pressed

Tags: javascript, objective-c, ios, xcode, html

I am displaying a webpage on one of tabbar items from main iOS tabbarcontroller and I would like to change tab bar item name when a button from this webpage is pressed. I have also full control of related webpage code so any web solution or native xcode function will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: are u able to handle button action on webpage..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

then u can use the following to change the tabBarItem name

```
appDelegate.tabBarController.tabBar.selectedItem.title = @"your tab name";
```

Comment: Thanks but change tab name natively is not a problem. I mean that I am able to change code as necesary to handle button action but I don't know how to handle it!

Comment: ok, check this delegate method of webView

- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType;

print the request-- u can work from this, remember to set delegate of webview

Answer (score 0):

Since you have total control over the Website's code, you can get the "Title" of the web-page and set it:

```
title = NSString StringWithFormat (@"%@",webPageTitle);
self.title = NSLocalizedString(title, title);
```

Comment: good but how to capture the event when button is pressed in order to trigger native function?